Error 43 on Hyper-V DDA with Nvidia P4000 Quadro GPU
My Nvidia Quadro GPU (P4000) was previously functioning correctly but has now started to display Error 43 in Hyper-V.
Here's the command to enable GPU passthrough on my server computer, which has two GPUs:
Enable-VMIntegrationService -VMName Windows11 -Name "Guest Service Interface"

Set-VM -Name Windows11 -AutomaticStopAction TurnOff
Set-VM -GuestControlledCacheTypes $true -VMName Windows11
Set-VM -LowMemoryMappedIoSpace 3Gb -VMName Windows11
Set-VM -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 32768Mb -VMName Windows11
Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice -Force -LocationPath 'PCIROOT(14)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0000)'
Add-VMAssignableDevice -LocationPath 'PCIROOT(14)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0000)' -VMName Windows11

This worked for many days. It suddenly stopped working. The last thing I did with the Guest VM was to enable Bitlocker, but I have since turned it off when the GPU issue started to happen.
I've attempted to reboot the host machine multiple times, as well as the guest Windows 11 VM, but the GPU still shows Error 43. What are the steps to debug and fix this issue?
I ran the command 'Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice -Force -LocationPath 'PCIROOT(14)#PCI(0000)#PCI(0000)' and it failed, throwing an error. I forgot to copy the error, but now the VM won't boot.

